# Rails - how to fetch data with jQuery function from partial?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, function, partial

I have this structure of my page:

**new.html.haml**

```
%h1 New
= render 'form'
```

**_form.html.haml**

```
= form_for @article do |f|
  .field
    = f.label "Category"
    = f.select(:category_id, @categories.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }, {:prompt => "-- Chose --"}, :onchange => "update_articles_div(this.value)")
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save'

#articlesDiv
  = render :partial => 'articles', :object => @articles
```

**_articles.html.haml**

```
- @articles.each do |articles|
  = link_to 'Add', add_article_articles_path, :remote => true, :onclick => "add_article($('#article_category_id').val())"
```

and JS function:

```
function add_article(category_id) {  
    alert(category_id);
}
```

I thought that if I click on the **Add** link, then jQuery fetch the **category_id** value and put it  into the JS action and I will see in **alert** window the **category_id**. However, instead of that I see only empty alert window.

Thus, how to fetch the value and display it in the alert window?

What I am trying to do: in the partial are **Add** links and after clicking them I am trying to fetch some data from inputs that are above of rendering the partial and altogether send them to a controller action.

Thank you

Comment: Are you certain you have this `$('#article_category_id')` value somewhere in the page? Like in a hidden input or something? Looking at the code you showed us, i don't think you can get this value.

Comment: I have made a stupid mistake while testing -- the code above is working, but I put into the 'select' drop down the first item empty **-- Chose --** -> which was the reason why the alert window showed no text.

Comment: Also, you must remember your partial is going to use local variables, not instance. Something else to comprehend, although I think your inclusion  of the partial will allow it to use the instance variables you've defined in your controller